# How to make a stand by button?

Tags: pi-3, gpio, touchscreen

I am using an Raspberry Pi 3b and a 7 inch hdmi waveshare touchscreen that connects to rpi with a hdmi cable and a micro usb cable.

I want to program a push button from GPIO pins to make the screen on/off when the button is pressed.

I can turn the backlight off with `vcgencmd display_power 0` command but the touch is still working and when the screen turns on again I can see that the touches that I have made is applied.

How can I turn off touch like the backlight in this screen?

Comment: Are you sure that's a feature that's available in software for your device? Which exact model do you have? Can you find a link to a datasheet on it? All those things would improve your question.

Comment: have you done any research about disabling the touch panel?

Comment: @T.M. This is my exact model: [link](https://www.waveshare.com/wiki/7inch_HDMI_LCD_(B))

Comment: @jsotola Yes. But i didn't a proper way for doing it.

Answer (score 0):

Find out what `xinput` ID your touchscreen has, then disable it with

```
xinput set-prop $ID "Device Enabled" 0
```

Note: a proper standby (halting CPU/RAM, not just the screen backlight) is [not possible](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/111409/33476) on the Pi, at least with stock kernel/drivers.

Comment: I have searched about it. I think the ID will change every time that rpi boots and how can I solve this?

Comment: @Nimda It will only change if you keep adding/removing input devices between reboots. If this is the case, you can parse the `xinput` output and find the ID by name.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure about disabling touch, but for the button press action, that's easy with gpiozero:

```
from gpiozero import Button
from subprocess import check_call
from signal import pause

def screen_off(btn):
    check_call(['vcgencmd', 'display_power', '0'])
    btn.when_held = screen_on  # swap actions

def screen_on(btn):
    check_call(['vcgencmd', 'display_power', '1'])
    btn.when_held = screen_off  # swap actions

shutdown_btn = Button(17, hold_time=2)
shutdown_btn.when_held = screen_off

pause()
```

Alternatively you could use `when_pressed` or `when_released`, or even use two combined.

See a [similar example](https://gpiozero.readthedocs.io/en/stable/recipes.html#shutdown-button) and see [Button docs](https://gpiozero.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api_input.html#button).

Comment: Sorry, but that doesn't answer the question. If you wanted to share your knowledge, better ask&answer your own question than posting an answer which doesn't fit.