# The RPi 4 does not support Power Management - is it due to lack of capability, or lack of will?

Tags: power-management, device-tree

It's clear enough from [this Q&A](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/111414/83790) and the `null` output from `cat /sys/power/state` that the Raspberry Pi does not currently support the Linux kernel's [Power Management](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/v5.4/power/index.html) features. This explains why there is no [sleep mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sleep_mode) for the RPi. As RPi production numbers may now be in the [range of one million units/month](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raspberry_Pi#Sales), I find this a little surprising, and so I'm posting this question in an effort to learn whether RPi's lack of support for Power Management is due to:

1. RPi hardware simply lacks the capability, or
2. It's not a development priority

I realize this may be asking for an opinion instead of an answer. If it is, it should probably be closed. The second question may well be subjective - unless The Foundation has publicly announced their objectives. But I'm hopeful that the first question can be answered more objectively - if not definitively - by those more familiar with the ARM technology and architecture used in the RPi.

Comment: What would be the point? The Pi consumes less power than most computers in sleep mode and boots in a short time. Sleep mode requires a sophisticated power supply (which would cost more than most Pi). I used to sleep my laptop overnight to save battery  and to facilitate rapid boot, but since I replaced the HDD with a SSD I just shutdown.

Comment: @Milliways: Have you measured that? I can close the lid on my MBP with a fully charged battery, open it 2 days later, and still have 100%. 30-40 mA seems quite a lot to me.